# In multipage $.mobile.changePage("#test") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi all I have html file in that there are various different pages in div. Now I want to navigate from one page to another I am using `$.mobile.changePage("#test")`  for this but navigation to test.html is not take place. If I use different html file for test.html and call it as `$.mobile.changePage(("test.html"));`  then navigation takes place.

I also tried with loadPage, but it also does not solve my issue. Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="firstPage" onclick=callSecondPage() class="type-home">

        <div data-role="button">
            <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="firstPage" id="firstPage">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function callSecondPage()
            {
                alert ("Inside callPage");

                $.mobile.changePage('#secondPage');

            }
        </script>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="secondPage"  onclick=callThirdPage() class="type-home">

        <div data-role="button">
            <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="secondPage" id="secondPage">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function callThirdPage()
            {
                alert ("Inside callPage");

                $.mobile.changePage('#thirdPage');

            }
        </script>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="thirdPage"  onclick=callFourthPage() class="type-home">

        <div data-role="button">
            <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="thirdPage" id="thirdPage">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function callFourthPage()
            {
                alert ("Inside callPage");

                $.mobile.changePage('#fourthPage');

            }
        </script>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="fourthPage" class="type-home">

        <div data-role="button">
            <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="fourthPage" id="fourthPage">
        </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="fifthPage" class="type-home">

        <div data-role="button">
            <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="fifthPage" id="fifthPage">
        </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="sixthPage" class="type-home">

        <div data-role="button">
            <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="sixthPage" id="sixthPage">
        </div>

</div>
```

before comes to above html file  navigate to other pages, And now `$.mobile.changePage('#secondPage');` secondPage is not navigated from firstPage.  But if same code I placed in index.html (i.e entry point of application then proper navigation takes place.

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTML that you're using for the JQM pages?

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#test"))
```

Is the call to $.mobile.changePage waiting for page load? You need to let us see some code here...

Comment: using this I got error as: TypeError: Result of expression 'toPage.data( "page" )' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js:2843

Comment: $.mobile.changePage("#test") should be sufficient so I'm not surprised that this didn't make a difference. If the page isn't changing then JQM isn't finding a div with data-role="page" using that id. Unfortunately without seeing the HTML that you've used I can't be of any more assistance.